# CSS: How to float 3 divs side by side for width:100% without messing up?

Tags: css, css-float, width, border

I want to put three `div { width:33%; border: 3px solid #333;}` aside within a page. But it just fails, like if the sum was superior to 100%.

**How to float 3 divs side by side and occupying a width:100% without messing up ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The borders are not counted within the div's box. They are to **add**, and thus are messing up your set, its width is : 3boxes * (33%+**3px+3px**), which is likely more than 100%.

Use :

```
.left {
  float:left; 
  width:33.3%;
  border: 3px solid #333;
}
.box-sizing { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

See [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxmL/2/), you can resize the result box it stays perfect. :)

Comment: I'd like to note that the box-sizing property is not supported by IE lt 8. ;)

Comment: And?  IE6&7 are dead browsers.

Comment: Well, I focus on the futur not on the past.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question. And while I think Hugolpz answer is fine I couldn't resist to play around on jsfiddle. So my answer is rather an experimental solution and not tested in real world scenarios. But I find it interesting somehow. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrfGw/).

Markup:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="box one">1</div>
    <div class="box two">2</div>
    <div class="box three">3</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
// Color and height properties are just here for demonstration purposes.

.outer {
    position: relative; // make the parent a relative reference point to its children
    // overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
.box {
    position: absolute; // position all children absolute but relative to the parent
    width: 33.3%;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
.one {
    left: 0; // first box to the left
    background: red;
}
.two {
    left: 33.3%; // second box placed according to the width of the first box
    background: cyan;
}
.three {
    left: 66.6%; // third box placed according to the sum of widths of the first two boxes
    background: purple;
}
```

Left and right borders of neighbored boxes will overlap due to their absolute position. Where one would expect the borders to become 10px in that case they visually appear as 5px.

Comment: Using absolute positioning for layout fails in most real world situations because it requires knowing the height of the content.

Comment: @cimmanon Well yes, like I said untested et al. I was just motivated to play around and thought I would share my fiddle. :) Should we vote to delete the answer?

Comment: +1 This is a helpful solution. Definitely don't delete it, and it shouldn't have been down-voted either. I, for one, know my content height, so this is a valid solution, especially since the "box-sizing" solution in the other answers doesn't work in IE8 and below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is you set the div size to be 33% + 6px border per div.

To solve this you can simply use box-sizing and make sure you reset all the style

example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <style type='text/css'>
            * { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; } 
            .thirdContainer { float: left; display: block;  width: 33.33%; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="thirdContainer" style="background: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="thirdContainer" style="background: yellowgreen;"></div>
    <div class="thirdContainer" style="background: blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```